# Swagger UI with digest authentication

Tags: javascript, authentication, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I'm using Swagger to produce the documentation of my REST API. According to what is written around, the Swagger UI does not offer support for basic authentication (differently from the [online editor](http://editor.swagger.io)). My problem is that one of my APIs is a POST that require digest (not even basic) authentication.

A possible solution I found around is to add a fixed user:pass authentication header in the request via javascript code. This should be easily done according to the [Swagger UI documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) (see [Custom Header Parameters](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui#custom-header-parameters---for-basic-auth-etc)). I report the incriminated code line:

```
swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("key", new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("Authorization", "XXXX", "header"));
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. The `swaggerUi.api` field results uninitialised (null) after I initialise the SwaggerUi object, and as a consequence `swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations`is undefined. I tried initialising such fields in different way, failing every time. I tried also similar calls to the API I found in threads discussing this topic, but none of them has worked. Does anyone have an idea about that? The documentation is not particularly clear about that.

For completeness, I report the js snippet where I initialise the `Swagger UI`

```
  var urlPush = "./doc_push.yaml";
  window.swaggerUiPush = new SwaggerUi({
        url: urlPush,
        dom_id: "swagger-ui-container-push",
        supportedSubmitMethods: ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'patch'],
        onFailure: function(data) {
          log("Unable to Load SwaggerUI");
        },
        docExpansion: "list",
        jsonEditor: false,
        defaultModelRendering: 'model',
        showRequestHeaders: false,
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SwaggerClient.PasswordAuthorization` instead of `SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization` -

```
 var username = $('#input_username').val();
 var password = $('#input_password').val();
 var basicAuth = new SwaggerClient.PasswordAuthorization('basic', username, password);
 window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("basicAuth", basicAuth);
```

Comment: For sure, in that way it adds the header "Authorization: Basic XXXXXXX" (watch out, the new version does not want the 'basic' field to be present). The problem is that it seems to solve the Basic Authentication problem, not the Digest Authentication problem (which requires the MD% of the user:realm:pass).